# Can we have virtual action items in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider this case that there is a base class

```
public abstract class BaseController:Controller
{
    public virtual ActionResult  Index() => View();
}
```

obviously we cant have views for the base class due to it being abstract. Here are the derived classes:

```
public class MyController: BaseController
{
    // everything but no Index()
}

public class AnotherController:BaseController
{
    // again all except Index()
}
```

1. If we make a call **http://loclhost:666/My/Index** derived classes
   controller but the base class Index, would it correctly use the view
   of derived class?
2. If that is not possible then how can we fix it while avoiding
   repeating the Index() for all the concrete controller classes?

Comment: I might not understand the question correctly, but; You could make the `Index` method abstract: `public abstract ActionResult  Index();` So the derived classes must implement it.

Comment: Your pseudocode says: "everything but no Index()" in the derived controllers but you say "However the derived classes have Index views defined" - this is a little confusing? I think from your question that your comments in the pseudocode are wrong but it would be good to clarify or correct...

Comment: Also can you not pretty easily test how things work? Write some appropriate controllers, write some test views, run it and see what happens... Its an interesting question but so I'd definitely keep it and submit an answer but it just strikes me that you can test it pretty easily...

Comment: @Chris if I write it, run it absorb the knowledge into my brain and die , wouldn't it defeat the purpose of the stackoverflow platform?

Comment: @SimpleFellow you might not be not that unique. Creating this construction. It might be done several times. ;-)

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen  Actually I'm from Mars and testing the level of you earthlings!

Comment: @SimpleFellow: That's why I said you should submit an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works as such. Your code is correct and ASP.NET MVC will take the base class into account.

I tested it successfully with ASP.NET Core MVC. You have a typo in your code however: remove "return" from your lambda.

```
public virtual ActionResult  Index() => View();
```

Comment: clever earthling ...you got me!

Comment: That wasn't the purpose of my answer. ;-)